# How to run wlst script by .py file

Tags: python, wlst

I'm trying to run wlst script form .py file but it can not be done

Content of .py file :

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://localhost:8001')
sca_undeployComposite('http://localhost:8001','Hello','1.0','user='weblogic',partition='myPartition')
sca_deletePartition('myPartition')
sca_createPartition('myPartition')
sca_deployComposite('http://localhost:8001','C:\WLST\Test\Application.zip',user='weblogic',configplan='myPlan.xml', partition='myPartition')
exit()
```

when i run cmd file to execute script, Only connect() method is execute success. any command bellow it can not be execute. And error message appear: Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last): File "c:\WLS\script\filname.py", line 2, in ?
Name Error: sca_undeployComposite

Please help me to resolve it. Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The commands after the connect() line which are not regular WLST commands. They requires sca related libraries into CLASSPATH. if you look into your wlst.cmd or .sh file that is actually calling the environment setup file that could be setWLSEnv.sh/.cmd. If you run that from where you are having the this python script. That script will work, it is simple java CLASSPATH funda nothing else!

Probably you might be running wlst.cmd after navigating to the common bin folder like

```
cd /oracle/fmwhome/Oracle_SOA1/common/bin/.
```

instead you can run in your script like this

```
C:\WLS\script\>/oracle/fmwhome/Oracle_SOA1/common/bin/wlst.cmd filename.py
```

or

```
C:\WLS\script\>/oracle/fmwhome/Oracle_SOA1/common/bin/setWLSEnv.cmd
C:\WLS\script\>java weblogic.WLST filename.py
```

You can also refer for more sca related scripting: [WLSTByExamples](http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.in/2013/06/soa-retire-activate-composites.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this have been really useful for me :)